# If date is a holiday, then add days to date until date is no holiday

Tags: python, date

If day `x` is a holiday, then add `days` to day `x` until it is not a holiday.

```
def is_lastday_holiday(lastday):
   while lastday in sorted(holidays.AT(years=2017)):
      lastday + timedelta(days=1)
   return lastday
```

This results in an infinite loop. Any hints?

Comment: You didn't assign `lastday` in the loop.

Comment: You want `lastday += timedelta(days=1) # note the +=, not +`

Comment: `name 'holidays' is not defined`

Comment: @ArcherGodson maybe it is defined before function.

Comment: @coldspeed thanks, that's right and helpful.

Comment: @Arman yes, it's imported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed assigning and updating `lastday`.

```
def is_lastday_holiday(lastday):  
    while lastday in sorted(holidays.AT(years=2017)):  
        lastday = lastday + timedelta(days=1) 
    return lastday
```

Alternatively,

```
lastday += timedelta(days=1)
```